# not able to send data with http.post ionic

Tags: javascript, java, php, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm not able to send data through http.post with the following code. I'm able to get a response but not able to send data for processing.

the following is the code:

appServer.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'server',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class appServer {
    connectServer: any;
    send_data: any;
    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }
    serverConnect(){
        let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
        let req = {call: 'insert_BOT',data: this.send_data};
        this.http.post('http://www.o9village.com/myBOT_api/botfeeds.php',JSON.stringify(req), headers)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .subscribe(res=>{
            this.connectServer = res;
            console.log(res);
        },(err)=>{
            console.log('Can\'t fetch data');
        })
    }
}
```

botfeeds.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

echo json_encode($array);
```

console.log(res) returns a null value/

Comment: updated the full code for appServer.ts. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can not send post data i.e. when you send data with

Header **Content-Type: application/json**
you can not see it in $_POST variable in php.

You have to send data with

Header **Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

Then you will be able to see Post data on server.

Comment: still not working. Still getting an empty array for $_POST

Comment: What response you are getting. I tried and getting 403.

Comment: response is an object containing the post array(which returns empty) and 2 other text elements.

Answer (score 0):

http.post takes three parameters

1) url,

2) data you want to send,

3)header

in the header you specify as json 
but you are doing JSON.stringify it will convert it into string may be this is the error. send it as it is may solve the problem.

try this

```
this.http.post('http://www.o9village.com/myBOT_api/botfeeds.php', req, headers)
```

Comment: I simply added $_POST as an array and returned it back. the array shows post with null value.

Comment: no try print that in php and see before you retured it back

Comment: and also see send some text. print it what is it sending

Comment: Yes. Text added at backend(php) can be echoed successfully. Its the i set them up in the array with 2 other parameters consisting of some text i added. The text can be returned but the element containing the post array is empty.